# VBA code to replace Header/Footer instead of only the main body

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

I have found and written a code in order to replace text within a word document through an excel sheet. But the problem is that the code only applies to the main body of the text and not on the header/footer of the document. So then I used the StoryRange within the code and the code is the following, but it still gives me an error for the storyrange? If I remove the storyrange, then the replace only works for the body and not the header/footer? Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

```
   Sub CompleteTask()

'Defining the dim
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim msWord As Object
Dim itm As Range
Dim myStoryRange As Object

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsh = Sheets("Home")
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Inserting the With Loop to open the Word Document
With msWord
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & wsh.Range("B3").Value & ".docx")
    .Activate
    
    For Each myStoryRange In msWord.StoryRanges
        With myStoryRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("C").Cells
            .Text = itm.Value2
            .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, -1).Value2
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .Execute Replace:=2
            Next
        End With
    Next myStoryRange
    
    'Saving the File into a new folder
    .ActiveDocument.SaveAs wsh.Range("B5").Value & "\" & wsh.Range("B4") & ".docx"
    .Quit
    'SaveChanges:=True

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to loop through each section of the document and then through each of the headers and footers (there are 3 types) in the section.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt so would that just be With .ActiveDocument.Sections.Headers.Find .. and then the rest remains the same?

Comment: No, because that wouldn't be a loop would it?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt If I understand it correctly, I would need 3x loops. one for each section (header, body, footer). But since I have one WITH and FOR EACH running for the .Content.Find. Shouldnt I just copy all of it again for Header? But how do I define the header?

Comment: Loop through [StoryRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.storyranges) should be easier - https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm if you simply want to change just main body, header and footer then use If Else/Select statement to exclude the stories that you don't want

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. To keep the code simpler the find part will need to be split into a separate routine. You should also set a reference to the Word library and declare your variables with their specific datatypes. There is no benefit to using late binding when working across the Office applications. Also, avoid using `ActiveDocument` and instead use something like `Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(...)` so that you can reference the specific document directly.

Comment: @RaymondWu - yes, story ranges are a good option if you don't have any knowledge of the document's construction, though the possibility of nested story ranges makes the code a bit messy. That said the multiple finds don't really make a simple solution possible.

Comment: @Timothy Yes I agree with you on that, the multiple Find-Replace makes it difficult to have a simple solution, it just seems that StoryRanges approach is somewhat easier (at least to me). It's his call though!

Comment: If you have control of the original documents, it might be better to have StyleRef fields in the headers/footers that refer to text in the body. Then the replace in the body will do it all. See: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF and http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm When coding in Word, if you can, you want to use Word's built-in functions and features rather than trying to write around them.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your comments and insights about the StoryRange. I think that it will be better to use the StoryRange instead. I will try to read up on it and try to implement it as correctly as possible

Comment: @RaymondWu I have updated my code with the storyrange function, but I can not make it work. Can you kindly have a look at it and let me know what it is I am doing wrong? Thanks a bunch!